# Typescript conditional type on string includes

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, template-literals

I'd like to type a function that takes a string as input and returns a list if the string contains '[]', and an object otherwise. Something like that:

```js
function func<T = any>(query: string): typeof query extends `${any}[]${any}` ? Array<T> : T {
  if (query.includes('[]')) {
    return [] as T[]
  }
  return {} as T
}
```

Except it doesn't work, the function return type is only string.

I'm using the latest typescript version (4.3.2).

Could you help me with that ?

Comment: this is not possible. and does not make sense within typescript. typescript does not exists on runtime. so you use some constant declared before runetime and you can already see it so you can tell what type it would be. or you get dynamic parameter (eg from user input), in that time there is no ts and you do not need these types.

Comment: It's not a user input, and yes it's a constant, I just would have prefered for the caller not to have to type the return value himself.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that with type parameters, not real function parameters:

```
function func<S extends string, T = any>(): S extends `${infer A}[]${infer B}` ? Array<T> : T {

}
const testFun = func<'a[]b'>();
const testFun2 = func<'ab'>();
```

Comment: I found that, but it means that the caller has to put the same string in the type parameter and in the function arguments. Too bad if it's not possible otherwise

Comment: hm ii didnt know about that. but in this case you can use typeof. since it would be strin g literal. const testFun = func<typeof yourConstant>();

Comment: and in body of that function you won't be able to infer type, what will be the result?

Comment: I trust the body of my function to respect the typing of my function ^^